# Output to multiple files in crontab

Tags: linux, cron, python, output, write

In crontab I have set up a python script to run every 5 min, and output to a specific file

```
   */5   *     *   *    *   sudo /home/pi/MyProgram.py  -o /home/pi/MyFile.csv
```

How can I take the same output of my python program and output to two files

```
       */5   *     *   *    *   sudo /home/pi/MyProgram.py  -o /home/pi/MyFile.csv "AND" /home/pi/MyFile2.dat
```

Comment: Do you know how to do what you want from the command line, or a script that you run from the command line? If not, start by solving that problem (crawl before you walk).  If yes, what’s stopping you from doing the same thing in crontab? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: modify your MyProgram.py so that it can take multiple `-o` options, and write to all of them. Or write to the file specified by the `-o` AND to stdout, and redirect stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `tee` command.

```
echo "something" | tee filea fileb
```

will write the "something" to both `filea` and `fileb`

Comment: And to standard output. To only write to the files and not to standard output, add `>/dev/null` at the end.

Comment: or just `| tee file_a > file_b`